# Disabling Eureka Client when running Zuul Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am trying to use Zuul as reverse proxy without discovery server. Things seem to work. One thing that bothers me is that the discovery client keeps looking for a discovery server. How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: Your summary doesn't really match the question. Is it basic auth you are interested in or discovery?

Comment: Your title and question do not match. Please provide more information. What are your dependencies?

Comment: Sorry Guys! Let me correct the title. I think I also found the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution is as simple as adding this to application.yml:

```
eureka:
  client:
    enabled: false
```

As suggested by  @spencergibb below, excluding the eureka dependencies also disables the discovery client. I ended up choosing this latter approach as it inherently simplifies my build.

Comment: you can also exclude the eureka dependencies from your project.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I would happily accept that as the answer.

Comment: They both work, just update your answer with the other option as well.